# Is this a bug in Excel's handling of Office Open XML metadata?

Tags: excel, metadata, openxml

It seems that Excel's handling of the metadata you can associate with cells is broken, but I'd be interested to hear if anyone else has tried (successfuly or otherwise) to use this feature.

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to report bugs against Excel, I've posted a full description of the problem with code to reproduce it here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/excel/thread/c7f9747a-1d03-4415-97d4-d9aa58b4d240 but I'll repeat the salient details.

In short it seems that Excel is removing, and incorrectly re-indexing the metadata I programatically associate with cells.

### First, a summary of the relevant parts of the specification:

From OOXML 18.9: There are two types of metadata: "cell metadata" and "value metadata".

Cell metadata follows the cell as it moves. Value metadata follows the value through formulae etc.

From OOXML 18.3.1.4: The c (cell) element has cm and vm attributes which are both documented as "The zero-based index of the [cell|value] metadata...in the Metadata Part"

From OOXML 18.9.17: The valueMetadata is "a collection of block element that each define the value metadata for a particular cell". "Cells in the workbook index into this collection".

The valueMetadata contains bk elements which in turn contain rc (metadata record) elements

From OOXML 18.9.15: rc elements have t (type index) and v (value index) attributes. t is a 1-based index into metadataTypes and v is a 0-based index into the futureMetadata element which matches the name of the metadata type.

### Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
...
<c vm="0">  <!-- vm points to the first bk inside valueMetadata below -->
...
<x:valueMetadata>
  <x:bk>
    <x:rc t="1" v="0" />  <!-- t points to the first metadataType below. v points to the first bk in the futureMetadata below (whose name matches the metadataType to which t points) -->
  </x:bk>
</x:valueMetadata>
...
<x:metadataTypes>
  <x:metadataType name="MyMetaType" ... />  <!-- name dictates which futureMetadata valueMetadata's v attribute indexes into -->
</x:metadataTypes>
...
<x:futureMetadata name="MyMetaType" ...>
  <x:bk>
    <x:extLst>
      <x:ext xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" uri="http://example.com/extension" p5:value="test value" xmlns:p5="http://example.com/extension" />
    </x:extLst>
  </x:bk>
</x:futureMetadata>
...
```

### The Problem

From what I can tell, for values of n > 2, if you associate n cells with metadata, Excel will drop the last piece of metadata, and the one at index 1, and it will do so silently. The indices are then 0..n-3, and the association for all but the first (0 index) will be wrong. This renders the future metadata totally useless.

For n == 1, Excel just removes the last piece of metadata (index 1). If we try 1-based indexes for the vm attribute on the c element, we get different behaviour. This may not be relevant as it is contrary to the specification, but the slightly better behaviour might indicate an off-by-one error:

```
n    Deleted Indices (0-based)     Deleted Indices (0-based) 
     when using 0-based indices    when using 1-based indices
1    0                             None
2    1                             1
3    1,2                           1
4    1,3                           1
5    1,4                           1
6    1,5                           1
```

Answer (score 1):

A suitable workaround from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7f9747a-1d03-4415-97d4-d9aa58b4d240/bug-in-excels-handling-of-metadata-or-at-least-a-deviation-from-the-open-office-xml-specification?forum=excel#dbcdee5d-6677-46b0-8ea5-53434ec4cdb9).

> Bit late to the party but only recently started using OpenXML. Easiest fix is to avoid Metadata and just use extension lists. They can be customised and applied at the cell level.

So instead of fiddling around with the metadata part, you can just write this to avoid the problem, you mentioned:

```
<c>
  <extLst>
    <ext uri="http://example.com/extension" p5:value="test value" xmlns:p5="http://example.com/extension">
      <p5:anotherValue>127</p:anotherValue>
    </ext>
  </extLst>
</c>
```